# What Junit test method could I use to test that the swapped numbers is equal to "5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7"?

Tags: java

Here is the class that will swap two elements of an array, what I want to do is add a Junit testing to see if the outputted changed values are equal to 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test { 
    public static <T> void swap(T[]n,int index1, int index2) {
        T temp= n[index1];
        n[index1]=n[index2];
        n[index2]=temp; 
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Integer[] n= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        System.out.println("before: "+Arrays.toString(n));
        swap(n,0,4);
        System.out.println("after: "+Arrays.toString(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: no, I want to compare 5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7 with the changed elements that's in the array

Comment: Code review side bar: as parameter names `object1` and `object2` are misleading.  Consider a more informative name such as `AtIndex` and `withOtherIndex`.

Comment: Looks like the proposed duplicate fully answers your question.

Comment: @jontro okay, but how do I pass numbers to the test class " assertArrayEquals(new int[]{5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7},somethinghere);"?

Comment: @Ashley `Arrays.equals(new Integer[]{5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7} , n)` if you want to check your array named `n`

Comment: @jontro thanks got it work now I used assertArrayEquals instead